# CHaMP Topo Processing Menu not active in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, convert, 3d-analyst

After converting a .tiff file to TIN, I have now installed the CHaMP Topo Processing Add-In which should allow me to convert Topo TIN to DEM. However, after installation, the entire toolbar is grey and inactive (including Convert Topo TIN to DEM from drop down). Any advice on why this might happen?

Comment: Which version of the toolbar are you using and which version of ArcGIS do you have installed? Do you have 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst licenses?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.1 and I have all licenses for it (3D and spatial analyst included). The Add-in that I installed is 5.0.8. Do you think that's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The toolbar is designed to work with a "SurveyGeodatabase", which is created in the first step of the Toolbar workflow. Unless you are working with a set of total station data, I think the toolbar is not the right fit for your needs/task.

This step in the toolbar actually relies on ESRI's "[TIN to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000077000000)" Geoprocessing tool, which can be accessed from ArcToolbox if you have the 3D analyst extension installed.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply. I tried doing that and I was not happy with the results so I am thinking TIN is somehow the issue. Is there any way I can convert a .tiff file to a DEM of some sort without going through TIN?

Comment: A DEM is just a raster of elevation. And a TIFF file is a raster. So why do you need to generate a TIN? What values are stored in your TIFF file? What is your main goal?

Comment: I realized they are similar type of files, but task involved the use of HEC-GeoRAS which only allowed me to use TIN or DEM, not tiff. I have sorted it in the end exporting it as GRID. Thank you